# How to use libegit2 with Magit

Tags: magit

I use Magit with following conditions.

- OS: 64bit Windows 10 version 20H2.
- Emacs: master branch of git repository, built with MSYS2, installed in `C:\Emacs`
- Magit: master branch of git repository, built with MSYS2, `BUILD_MAGIT_LIBGIT=false`
- Ghub: master branch of git repository, built with MSYS2
- Transient: master branch of git repository, built with MSYS2
- With-Editor: master branch of git repository, built with MSYS2
- dash.el: master branch of git repository
- treepy.el: master branch of git repository

As is explained currently I build Magit with `BUILD_MAGIT_LIBGIT=false`. So `git` is used as backend. But I took it into my head to use libegit2 with Magit and cloned its git repository.

There was no problem with building libegit2. By simply execute `make` at the top of source tree, `libegit2.dll`, `libgit.elc` and `libgit-autoloads.el` were created. So I installed `libgit.el`, `libgit.elc` and `libgit-autoloads.el` to `C:\Emacs\share\emacs\site-lisp` and `libegit2.dll` to `C:\Emacs\bin`. Next I rebuilt and reinstalled Magit with `BUILD_MAGIT_LIBGIT=true`. After that I restarted Emacs and started Magit with `M-x magit`. Then Magit successfully started but it still used `git` as backend.

So would someone please explain how to use libegit2 with Magit?

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue on the libegit2 git repository.